# Allow user to edit once in django

Tags: python, django

**Details:**

I have a teacher dashboard where a teacher can create and share worksheets with other teachers. When any worksheet is shared with other teachers they can (but not necessary) provide feedback on that worksheet, which will be visible to the creator of worksheet.

Now I have a model which stores this sharing thing as follows:

```
class SharingWS(TimeStampWS):
    shared_by = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_by')
    shared_with = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_with')
    worksheet = models.ForeignKey('WorkSheet', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    flag = models.BooleanField()
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

as soon as the worksheet is created, an entry is created in the model with default `flag=True`.

**Problem**

Now how can I give **only** one chance to other teachers to review the worksheet. Once they have given a feedback, they cant do it again and if they dont give feedback it will be assumed approved after 2 days.

*There are similar questions but for voting, where there is no previous entry in db and you can lookup. In my case an entry is already created so I can't use that concept.*

Comment: cannot you use created_at date column and is_viewed boolean column which would help in the problem that you have specified?

Comment: What is the `flag` field meant for? Keep `create_date` for the worksheets. Only one chance for feedback - You can have a Feedback model per Worksheet per reviewer, which is created when a feedback is given, and same is visible to the creator of the worksheet. Keep the fields - `[worksheet_id, created_by]` unique, so that you do not have multiple feedbacks from the same user for the same worksheet. 

For auto-approval after 2 days - you need to have a cron-job for it. which picks such worksheets without feedback, `current_time -
 creation_time > 2 days`, and marks them approved.

Comment: @Anvesh `flag` field is working kind of `is_approved`. @NihalSharma your suggestion seems to work. I am inheriting from TimeStamp model which has `created_at` field, So I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: why downvote? isn't the problem clear? Or if it has been asked before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint from @Nihal and @Adam I solved it as follows.

Since I am already inheriting from `TimeStampWS`, I added a new field `last_updated` along with `created_at`. Now my models looked as followed:

```
class TimeStampWS(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SharingWS(TimeStampWS):
    shared_by = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_by')
    shared_with = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_with')
    worksheet = models.ForeignKey('WorkSheet', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    flag = models.BooleanField()
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Now since as soon as the worksheet is created its `created_at` and `last_updated` time will have the difference in millisecond or at max in seconds. So I just used the date, hour and minute part to compare that whether teacher has provided feedback or not, This is my logic part:

**views.py**

```
def worksheet_review(request, id_r):
    current_time = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

    if request.method=='POST':
        # got desired ShareWS object here
--->    creation_time = share_instance.created_at.replace(second=0,microsecond=0)
--->    modification_time = share_instance.last_updated.replace(second=0,microsecond=0)

        if creation_time==modification_time:
            # adding extra fields in the object
            share_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('worksheet:worksheet_review_success'))

        elif current_time - creation_time > datetime.timedelta(days=2):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('worksheet:worksheet_review_once'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Feedback` model, with a `OneToOneField` to `SharingWS`.  Now, you can create a maximum of one `Feedback` instance per `SharingWS`, like so:

```
class SharingWS(TimeStampWS):
    shared_by = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_by')
    shared_with = models.ForeignKey('members.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shared_with')
    worksheet = models.ForeignKey('WorkSheet', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class Feedback(models.Model):
    sharing_ws = models.OneToOneField('app_name.SharingWS', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feedback')
    flag = models.BooleanField()
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide example for this? And for storing feedback count isn't that too much to create a new database table ?

Comment: It's not storing the feedback count, it's storing the feedback itself.  I'll add an example now.

Comment: @sgauri I've now added an example.

Comment: thank you @Adam. I solved it without creating new model, with the help of existing `TimeStamWS` model. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the condition if there exists record which has:

1. `shared_by` - owner of worksheet
2. `shared_with` - teacher that shared his opinion
3. `worksheet` - specific worksheet

If it exists it means that specific teacher shared his opinion. Period
For example such query:

```
SharingWS.objects.get(shared_by=Bob, shared_with=John, worksheet=BobsWorksheet)
```

looks for John's opinion about Bob's worksheet. If this query returns object it means that John can not share another opinion and you should disable it for him.

Comment: I cant do this, because as soon as the worksheet is created all 3 ForeignKeys are created in model.

Comment: So add the flag to your model called 'reviews' or 'evaluated' or whatever name is matching your case. Default value will be False. After first save (when sending form data) change this flag to True, which will indicate that that teacher already evaluated the worksheet.

Comment: yeah, this is also an option to explore. What I have done is checking the difference between modified time and created time of worksheet, if that difference is not same(seconds and miliseconds attributes removed) that means user has made an edit. thanks